# PhpStorm - How to deal with untrusted 3rd party URL server certificates

Tags: ssl, phpstorm

**PhpStorm version 2017.2.3**:

I am suddenly getting notifications such as the screenshot below, and they're persistent:

[image]

I believe (as you may be able to gather from the image), that what is happening is that PhpStorm is trying to connect to the `http://www.viridor.co.uk` domain and then is being presented with an untrusted certificate from the (https) domain varient.

I keep telling PhpStorm to reject this certificate. I don't want it saved. But PhpStorm keeps bringing up this notice.

## What I've tried:

I have read through the `settings` menu to see if I can find a way of sorting this but have not found anything suitable:

## What I'd like to achieve:

- Why does PhpStorm reject the certificate, can we edit these rejection criterias? this is the first time I've seen this and I'm sure PhpStorm has been checking a multitude of links from various project sites I work on. (*please see below some certificate diagnostics*)
- How can I get PhpStorm to remember my rejection for this certificate?
- If not, how can I turn off PhpStorm checking URLs outside the project scope (hopefully for just this project rather than all projects)?

## Extra info:

I have run the url (viridor.co.uk) through the Qualys SSLTest and it came back

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

[source](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.viridor.co.uk).

I would like to think that this certificates problems are the direct cause of this issue, but now I'd like to know how I can solve this issue.

Comment: What PhpStorm version do you use?

Comment: @VladLuchansky it is version 2017.2.3

Comment: When exactly do you receive this warning? Just when opening the file? Or when opening it in browser? Or when debugging it? I can't get the same result here.

Comment: @VladLuchansky it is when the file is open in the editor, every 60 seconds or so, the notice comes up. The notice does not appear on first opening the file, it seems to be when PhpStorm works through "checking" the URL links in the HTML of the file.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd-party plugins installed? Did you try to disable them?

Comment: @VladLuchansky I have no third party plugins installed on this project.